# What do we call a specific place we visit with a specific person?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

What do we call a place that we often visit with a specific person whenever we meet?
For example, when I go out with my old friends, we go to the same place we used to 2-3 years before.

Comment: One way to describe it would be as "our usual [haunt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haunt)".

Comment: Is that a place you used to go to 2-3 years ago, stopped going to for a while and have now started using again or is it a place you have been going to regularly for the last 3 years? (I understand that you might have stopped going anywhere for a while because of Covid-19). The phrases for somewhere you have used continuously and almost exclusively are largely different from ones you went to habitually in the past but have had a break from.

Comment: MarcInManhattan's *haunt* is good; Merriam-Webster has as synonyms of haunt (noun) "hangout, purlieu, rendezvous, resort, stamping ground, stomping ground".

Comment: @BoldBen it was the place where me and my friends used to go everyday to have some snacks after academy but due to changing schools we couldn’t meet.Now after months we will be revisiting the same place.So what word we will use for that place?

Comment: In that case "Our old stamping (or stomping ground)" as suggested by others would be suitable. "Our usual haunt" or "Our usual place" would have been appropriate before you moved schools.

Comment: In America it would be _our hangout_, with stress on _hang_, not _out_. Nominalization of _[place where] we hang out_ (with stress on _out_, not _hang_, because it's a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1):

**[Rendezvous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rendezvous)** /ˈrɒn.deɪ.vuː/

> a place where a particular group of people often go or meet, by
> arrangement or habit: